# Transistor Series Regulator calculation

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, calculation

I am new to electronics and have a limited knowledge. I tried calculating the values for a series transistor regulator to simulate in Multisim but still could not figure out a way to do this.

The two transistors are TIP122G and BC182. Please help me to calculate the zener value and the values for the resistors to get an output of 5.6V. The input is 10V

The BE drop of the TIP122 is considered as 1.2V and of the BC182 0.75V

I tried with some formulas and still could not get the simulation right. Please help me.

Edit-
Apart from all the above details the output current spec was given. It is 10mA nominal.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the calculations you have done to get values for R3, R4 and D1 ? Please add more details about the simulation results. For regulator circuits, you need to have a specification on the maximum and minimum values for V1 as well as load. Use the *small* edit button to add these details to the question.

Comment: What are the circumstances on the base that cause TR2 to start to activate?

Comment: Ah, let me see.  The output voltage is roughly determined by R3, R4, and D1. I usually make very roughly calculation and use variable resisters to test out. As I remember Vo = Vz * (R4 + R4) / R4, or something like that.

Comment: Hi The nominal output current should be 10mA. I have done a lot of paper work. Nothing seems to be correct for me :( Really sad right now.

Comment: What do you mean nominal output current is 10mA? TIP122 is a powerful guy (I used to use 2N3055 or 2N/MJE2955) and the output should be at least 5A, with a big heat sink.

Comment: 10mA is what my lab sheet says :(

Comment: Can you tell how you have calculated the values for R3, R4, D1 ? As well as the simulation results that you currently have. It would also be good to update the picture with one that has values marked for all components, even if the corresponding simulation is not working properly. With only this schematic, and no values or a description of what is going wrong in the simulation, it is difficult to guess.

Comment: @DilaraAmashi Write down 5.6 V at the emitter of TR1. Write down 6.8 V at the base of TR1. You want TR2's VCE to be at least 1 V, so TR2's emitter must be 5.8 V, or less. Find a zener voltage you like that is below that and then find out the proper operating current for it. That, if it is as least a tenth of your nominal output, will be your collector current for TR2. Now you can compute R2. Etc. It just flows out, like that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that "nominal" should instead be "approximately" so that the output current from TR1's emitter is allowed to be a few milliamperes above 10 mA when you have a 500 ohm load.

As a starting point, I suggest you choose desired values for the voltage drop across resistor R3.  For example, \$V_{R3} = 1.25\,\text{V}\$.  How did I choose VR3 = 1.25 V?  I want to ensure transistor TR2 is operating in forward-active mode.  If TR2's collector voltage VC2 is

$$
\begin{align*}
VC2 &= VB1\\
  &= VE1 + VBE1\\
  &= VOUT + VBE1\\
  &= (5.6\,\text{V}) + (1.2\,\text{V})\\
  &= 6.8\,\text{V}
\end{align*}
$$

I want to ensure TR2's collector-base diode is reverse biased by about 2.5 V (< value chosen from experience). This means I want TR1's base voltage VB2 to be about

$$
\begin{align*}
VB2 &= VC2 - VCB2\\
  &= (6.8\,\text{V}) - (2.5\,\text{V})\\
  &= 4.3\,\text{V}
\end{align*}
$$

and therefore the voltage across resistor R3 is

$$
\begin{align*}
V_{R3} &= VOUT - VB2\\
  &= (5.6\,\text{V}) - (4.3\,\text{V})\\
  &= 1.3\,\text{V}
\end{align*}
$$

Adjusting R3's voltage drop from 1.3 V to 1.25 V is not strictly necessary; but I can see by inspection (by experience) that changing this value will help me select a Zener diode in the next steps because VBE2 = 0.75 V.

Knowing VOUT = 5.6 V, VR3 = 1.25 V, and TR2's base-emitter voltage drop VBE2 = 0.75 V, you can determine the required voltage across Zener diode D1, i.e.,

$$
\begin{align*}
V_{D1} &= V_{OUT} - V_{R3} - V_{BE2} \\
    &= (5.6\,\text{V}) - (1.25\,\text{V}) - (0.75\,\text{V}) \\
    &= 3.6\,\text{V}
\end{align*}
$$

Use a website like Digi-Key, Mouser, etc. to find the part number of a Zener diode that has a 3.6 V drop (i.e., VZ = 3.6 V), e.g., 1N5227.

[*Hint: Select a part number that has a PSpice model in Modelsim so that you can simulate the circuit with that specific diode.*]

[*Hint: PSpice model names for diodes often have a 'D' in front of the OEM part number, e.g., D1N5227.*]

A Zener diode's Zener voltage VZ is specified at a specific Zener current IZ, i.e., VZ @ IZ.  Let's assume you use the 1N5227 diode.  That diode's data sheet indicates that VZ = 3.6 V @ IZ = 20 mA; therefore, you want to ensure TR2's emitter current IE2 is approximately 20 mA, i.e., IE2 = IZ = 20 mA.

Within Modelsim, if you look at the PSpice model source code for transistor TR2 you'll probably find that the forward current gain (beta) is specified as BF = 400.  Use 400 as the value of beta in your calculations involving transistor TR2 (see below).

Recall that

$$
IC = IB * beta\qquad\qquad(1)\\
IE = IB + IC\qquad\qquad(2)
$$

Assume transistor TR2 is operating in forward-active mode.  Use the equations (1) and (2) above to solve for transistor TR2's base current IB2 and collector current IC2.

[*Hint: You know IE2 = 20 mA and beta = 400. You have two equations and two unknowns, and you can solve for transistor TR2's base current IB2 and collector current IC2.*]

At this point, choose the desired current through resistor R3.  I recommend that IR3 be at least ten times IB2.  Also note that IR3 should be much less than your "nominal output current" of IOUT = 10 mA.  I recommend that IR3 be no greater than IOUT/10.

$$
10 \cdot IB2 \le IR3 \le IOUT/10
$$

Solve for transistor TR1's output current (i.e., transistor TR1's emitter current):

$$
IE1 = I_{LOAD} + I_{R3}
$$

[*Hint: Recall that you chose IR3, e.g., \$I_{R3}=1\,\text{mA}\$.  Use Ohm's Law to solve for \$I_{LOAD}\$.*]

Transistor TR1 is a Darlington pair.  Assume TR1 is operating in forward-active mode.  The data sheet for this transistor states that this transistor's minimum forward current gain (beta) is 1000.  Use equations (1) and (2) to solve for TR1's base current IB1 and collector current IC1.

At this point I think you have all the puzzle pieces you require to solve this circuit. Use Ohm's law, Kirchhoff's Current law, and Kirchhoff's Voltage law to solve for resistances R2, R3, and R4.

[*Note: For your final answer I suggest you select "standard" resistor values for resistors R2, R3, and R4. Do not use calculated values for these resistors.  Websites such as [RF Cafe](https://www.rfcafe.com/) provide [tables of standard resistor values](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/resistor-values.htm). For example, if your calculated resistance value for resistor R2 is 1234.56 ohms, you might select a 1 % tolerance resistor whose value is 1.24 kohm.*]

One final comment.  This is a [back of the envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation) solution; it is not a rigorous solution.  When you simulate this solution you might discover that the voltage and current values are off slightly; that is to be expected.  If you are not satisfied with the voltages and currents, I recommend you begin debugging the design by slightly adjusting the value of resistor R3 and re-simulating to see how that change affects the circuit's operation.  I also recommend that when you change a resistor's value, select a new value that is a standard resistor value and not some arbitrarily-chosen value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For such a low output current, using a darlington transistor is an overkill. I would recommend the following circuit. There is also a good application note [here](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2015/10/01/power-tips-how-to-design-a-robust-series-linear-regulator-with-discrete-components) about how to calculate the necessary resistor values. Basically, Rb should be small enough that sufficient base current flows into Q1. However, if it is too small, then the Zener diode will heat up. In the end you choose Rb as a compromise between base current and losses in Dz.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But that is what my lab experiment sheet has. I am new to the course and now feel like really lost